# R: bfs() in R to extract dist values separately

Tags: r, breadth-first-search

I have an adjacency matrix.

```
adjm <- matrix(sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.85,0.15)), nc=10)
for(i in 1:10)
{
for (j in 1:10) {
  if(i==j)
  { adjm[i,j]<-0 }
 } }
 colnames(adjm)<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J")
```

Then I convert this into adjacency graph.Then apply bfs() function. Since I need only the distance and the vertices, I include only "dist" as parameter.

```
 g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix( adjm )
 bfst<-bfs(g1, root=2, "all", dist=TRUE)

 $dist
 A B C D E F G H I J 
 0 2 1 3 1 1 2 2 1 2
```

From this I can separate dist as follows;

```
 bfst$dist
  A B C D E F G H I J 
  0 2 1 3 1 1 2 2 1 2
```

To access this dist individual component, I used bfst$dist[1]. But always display as follow.

```
bfst$dist[1]
A
0
```

If I want to extract them separately, How can I do it.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are trying to extract separately -- could you clarify? `bfst$dist` outputs just the distance, the A through J are just names. If you want the names alone `names(bfst$dist)` will get them.

Comment: I meant that I need to extract name (A) and distance (0) separately.  names(bsft$dist[1]) is useful answer too. Similarly, is there any way to get distance too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access an element without a name or a name without an element. The names won't, however, interfere with operations. Some examples below:

```r
vec <- 1:10
names(vec) <- LETTERS[1:10]
vec
#>  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J 
#>  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

# we can access the names if we want
names(vec)
#>  [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"

# or a name
names(vec)[1]
#> [1] "A"

# But the console output with both the name and
# the value is just a way of pretty-printing the
# result, it doesn't effect operations, e.g.
vec[1]
#> A 
#> 1
vec[1] * 10
#>  A 
#> 10

# however if you want to access an element
# without the name, use double brackets
vec[[1]]
#> [1] 1

# or to remove all names try
unname(vec)
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```